# Pthread_join() hangs on array of threads

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, synchronization

I've been working with pthreads, I've created them into an array using a for loop and producerThread[ index ] and conssumerThread[index] from 0 to however many the user wanted (for example 3 threads each).

The threads work properly and insert/remove items when required. They are in infinite while loops which break out using a global variable flag (endFlag) after main wakes up from the user specified sleep.

My issue is that I can't seem to get the threads to close, basically the pthread_join(thread[index], NULL) doesn't actually make it through either of my thread arrays and it just hangs.

Below is the close thread function, as mentioned above, the threads do actually work and are doing the output as I expect, but they just don't close as I expect them to.

I've tried moving the pthread_join() into main (currently in a function), moving through the array backwards index-- versus index++, moving the ordering of the two thread arrays (2 first then 1), and sleeping main again to hopefully make it so the threads all have a chance to end. All of these have had no success, also many of the issues I've seen online aren't exactly the same as what I've been experiencing.

```c
/*
    CloseThread function takes the pointer to the start of the array for the producer and consumer, the total threads (producer and consumer) entered by user
*/
void closeThreads( pthread_t *producerThread, pthread_t *consumerThread, int producerThreadCount, int consumerThreadCount )
{
    //flag to verify the thread closure
    int closed = -1;
    // for loop to close threads at consumerThread @ index value
    for ( int index = 0; index < consumerThreadCount; index++ )
    {
        // pthread_join returns 0 if successful, closing the thread @ index
        closed = pthread_join ( consumerThread[ index ], NULL );
        // thread failed to close if closed doesnt equal 0.
        if ( closed != 0 )
        {
            fprintf ( stderr, "Thread failed to create." );
            exit ( 4 );
        }//end of the failed to close issue.
    }// end of consumer thread close procedure
    // for loop to close the producer threads
    for ( int index = 0; index < producerThreadCount; index++ )
    {
        // closes a thread in the array producerThread @ index value
        pthread_join ( producerThread[ index ], NULL );
        // unsuccessful
        if ( closed != 0 )
        {
            fprintf ( stderr, "Thread failed to close." );
            exit ( 3 );
        }
    }// end of join producer threads
}// end of close threads
```

I should be getting the two thread arrays joining each thread with main but that is not happening and the console just hangs like its still computing.

EDIT: Sorry I fixed my testing of index-- to index++ like it actually is right now, either way both give the same issue of hanging.

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When `pthread_join` blocks that means the thread won't terminate.

Comment: The control structure shutting down the threads, along with the actual code in the threads detecting that control change, are *highly* relevant and need to be included as part of a [mcve]. The code presented.. is jacked. Ex: your `if (closed != 0)` check after joining your `producerThread[index]` . Um.. what set `closed` again ?? certainly not the line `pthread_join ( producerThread[ index ], NULL );`. If there is more than one producer thread, and assuming the signaling mechanics to shut them down isn't a functional myth, that code will *guarantee* a hard exit(3)

Comment: some code would be helpful, but is `endFlag` declared as `volatile`? If not, the optimizer may be optimizing out the actual load of that value each time through the loop for each of the threads if it sees `endFlag` is not being changed locally.

Comment: Yes, the ```pthread_join(producerThread[index], NULL;``` should have had closed =, and have changed that but I still don't get to that point in the function.

One of two things happens, the whole program hangs and never exits, or the program will have: 
```
Close thread in consumer for loop 
Consumer thread #0 closed = 0.
Close thread in consumer for loop 
```
And never finishes. 
The endFlag is seen by all the threads I had a printf line to verify this in the function that has the while loops and each thread prints it. I was advised not to add too much code.

Comment: You've been advised to show an MCVE/MRE (linked above). That means the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. An MCVE is not 1) not enough code to reproduce the problem (as you've done), nor 2) A 1000+ line code dump of everything you've written. Yes, it might take some work on your end to whittle out and determine what is and isn't necessary to include. In doing so, you might very well find the solution to your problem yourself. Describing your code (what you _think_ your code is doing) rather than showing it is almost always the wrong way to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your loops such as:

```
for ( int index = 2; index < consumerThreadCount; index-- )
```

Should probably be:

```
for ( int index = 0; index < consumerThreadCount; ++index )
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, I was testing the forloop working backwards and forwards and missed it during my review, I've added an edit. It does the same thing regardless.

Answer (score -1):

My issue ended up being when I broke out of my while loop I didn't use:

```c
sem_post(&semaphore);
```

This allowed the threads to be properly closed.